# Taking picture with camera intent rotate picture in portrait mode android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

Picture was taken successfully with camera but in portrait mode  on samsung galaxy s3 the picture gets rotated.  How can i solve this issue.
Camera intent is as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(xdestination));
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

In activity for result

```
 if (requestCode==CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST){

            //  Bitmap bm = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 

                Uri photo_uri = Uri.fromFile(xdestination);

                Editer.PHOTO_FROM=11;

                Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile=null;
                try {
                    decodeSampledBitmapFromFile = decodeUri(photo_uri);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                decodeSampledBitmapFromFile.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, bytes);

                File f  = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "user_image.jpg");

                try {

                    if(f.exists())
                        f.delete();

                    f.createNewFile();

                    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
                    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                    fo.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace( );
                    Log.d("ERROR", e.toString());
                }

            }
```

Comment: I too had a same problem and i rotate the picture after capturing it.

Comment: can you tell me how you rotate the picture? post your codes if possible or part of it

Comment: try my below code and let me know whether it is working for you or not.

Comment: good but not for my issue, i need to rotate the image saved in path File f  = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "user_image.jpg");

Comment: Then just change the path, Check my updated answer.

Comment: i need to change the rotation of picture saved in directory File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "user_image.jpg");    not to set on imageview dear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does an image captured using camera intent gets rotated on some devices on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066038/why-does-an-image-captured-using-camera-intent-gets-rotated-on-some-devices-on-a)

Answer (score 19):

Pass your taken picture and SDCard path of that picture into the following method which will return the correct oriented picture...

```
private Bitmap imageOreintationValidator(Bitmap bitmap, String path) {

    ExifInterface ei;
    try {
        ei = new ExifInterface(path);
        int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
        switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            bitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 90);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            bitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 180);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            bitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 270);
            break;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bitmap;
}

private Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap source, float angle) {

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    try {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(),
                matrix, true);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: sorry i did  decodeSampledBitmapFromFile = imageOreintationValidator(decodeSampledBitmapFromFile,f.getPath());
    decodeSampledBitmapFromFile.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, bytes); but no effect image is still in landscape

Comment: how to get "String path" from camera?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like below.

```
File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "user_image.jpg");
        if (photo.exists()) {
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photo
                    .getAbsolutePath());
            imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            imageView.setRotation(90);
        }
```

Step 1: Give a full path of your photo like `File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    , "Face.jpg");`

Step 2: Check whether photo is exist or not if yes then set it to image view and rotate it to 90 degree.

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
public int getCameraPhotoOrientation(Context context, Uri imageUri, String imagePath){
    int rotate = 0;
    try {
        context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(imageUri, null);
        File imageFile = new File(imagePath);

        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            rotate = 270;
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            rotate = 180;
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            rotate = 90;
            break;
        }

        Log.i("RotateImage", "Exif orientation: " + orientation);
        Log.i("RotateImage", "Rotate value: " + rotate);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rotate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no choice but read the image, rotate it and write the result back to SD card. The straightforward approach, using BitmapFactory, will easily [run into OutOfMemory exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203620/android-camera-intent-out-of-memory-error-and-rotation-error).

Alternatively, you can use [JPEG lossless rotation](http://www.betterjpeg.com/lossless-rotation.htm), using [jpegtran](http://www.ijg.org).

On SourceForge, there is a Java open source class [LLJTran](http://mediachest.sourceforge.net/mediautil/javadocs/mediautil/image/jpeg/LLJTran.html). The Android port is [on GitHub](http://github.com/bkhall/AndroidMediaUtil).

Answer (score 0):

Today I faced this problem. I know I'm late, but just in case someone needs it. In my case, if I pass the Uri inside the camera intent, then the output file was rotated. That is,

```kotlin
fun takePhoto() {
        val intent = Intent(android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, 
                Uri.fromFile(xdestination)) // <-- this line is the culprit for me
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST)
}
```

Then inside onActivity result, you get the bitmap rotated. I don't know why that happened.

So I didnot provide the Uri to the intent. That is I wrote this:

```kotlin
fun takePhoto() {
        val intent = Intent(android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST)
}
```

Therefore, inside `onActivityResult` I got the returned image as bitmap. Then I manually saved that bitmap inside the desired file / Uri.

```kotlin
  override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == PHOTO_CAPTURE_WITH_CAMERA_REQ_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      // 1. handle the image as normal bitmap
      val photo: Bitmap? = data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap;
      // handleImage(SharedData.pendingPhotoUri.pop())
      if (photo != null) {
        // inside handle camera
        handleCameraImage(photo)
      };
    }
  }

  private fun handleCameraImage(inputBitmap: Bitmap) {
    //2. according to previous implementation, this uri should be the final output image file.

    // 3. save the original bitmap in a temp image file
    val tempBitmapFile: String = requireActivity().cacheDir.absolutePath +"/temp_photo_"+System.currentTimeMillis();
    val fOuttemp: FileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(tempBitmapFile);
    inputBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOuttemp);
    fOuttemp.flush();
    fOuttemp.close();

    // 4. use ExifInterface to make sure the photo is in right orientation.
    val exifInterface: ExifInterface = ExifInterface(tempBitmapFile);
    val orientation: Int = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

    Timber.tag(TAG).e("orientation == " + orientation);
    var matrix = Matrix();
    var isRotationNeeded: Boolean = true;
    when(orientation){
      ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL -> {
        Timber.tag(TAG).e("when ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL");
        // do nothing I guess
        isRotationNeeded = false;
      }
      ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90 -> {
        Timber.tag(TAG).e("when ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90");
        matrix.setRotate(90f);
      }
      ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180 -> {
        Timber.tag(TAG).e("when ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180");
        matrix.setRotate(180f);
      }
      ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270 -> {
        Timber.tag(TAG).e("when ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270");
        matrix.setRotate(270f);
      }
      else -> {
        Timber.tag(TAG).e("when else");
        isRotationNeeded = false;
      }
    }

    // if in wrong orientation,
    //    rotate image and save it in the file from step 2.
    // else save the original image in the file from step 2.
    lateinit var outputBitmap: Bitmap;
    if(!isRotationNeeded) {
      outputBitmap = inputBitmap;
    }else{
      outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(inputBitmap, 0, 0, inputBitmap.width,
          inputBitmap.height, matrix, true);
    }

    val outputBitmapfile: File = File("your_awesome_file");

    val fOut: FileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(outputBitmapfile);
    outputBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
    fOut.flush();
    fOut.close();

    var outputPhotoUri:Uri = getUriForFile(requireActivty(), outputBitmapfile);



    // 5. finally use this photo / Uri to do whatever you want

  }

  fun getUriForFile(context: Context, file: File?): Uri? {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N || Config.ONLY_INTERNAL_STORAGE) {
      try {
        val destCopiedTempFile = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null).toString() + File.separator + "temp")
        FileBackend.copy(file, destCopiedTempFile)
        FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider", destCopiedTempFile)
      } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
          throw SecurityException(e)
        } else {
          Uri.fromFile(file)
        }
      }
    } else {
      Uri.fromFile(file)
    }
  }
```

This worked for me.